# Datagridview Column width

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

[image]I have problem related to datagridview in Winform.

I have a list of table names in my left panel. When I click on Table I show the table content in right panel. I am showing data in a datagridview by fetching data and assigning datasource to dgv.

I am setting following property to dgv.

```
dgTemp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
dgTemp.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
dgTemp.AutoSize = true;
dgTemp.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dgTemp.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
dgTemp.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
dgTemp.ReadOnly = true;
dgTemp.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dgTemp.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
dgTemp.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

My problem is there can be any number of columns in Datasource I am assigning to dgv. So if there are very few number of columns (say 1 or 2) the dgv size stands very small and the empty space on right side give very ugly look.
I can't use auto `autosizecolumnmode` to `fill` since when there is more columns all columns get shrink and expanding columns dont give me Scroll at bottom

so My requirement is

1. All space in datagridview should be filled. (should cover all area)
2. When there is more column, there should appear scroll, so it give better look

are there any events or properties which I can use ??

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
dgTemp.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

Update :

```
 dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 5; //use 5 because you want to start from 5
        //you can have a horizontal scroll bar with this code :
        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = 10; //you can choose every column you wanna start with that column
```

Update 2 :

```
int rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        int columns = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
        if (rows < 5 && columns < 10)
        {
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 5; //use 5 because you want to start from 5
            //you can have a horizontal scroll bar with this code :
            dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = 10; //you can choose every column you wanna start with that column
        }
```

Comment: For more number of columns (say 15) it give very thin columns and expanding any columns by drag, shrinks other columns. It would be great if I get an scrollbar at bottom when using this property. But I dont find scroll bar at bottom.... :(

Comment: @aliboy38.. Using your update code with 'autosizecolumnmode' to 'fill' dont give scroll. when using with 'autosizecolumnmode' to 'allcells', is shows scroll, but when there is small number of columns. it dont help and show the unwanted ugly look... :(

Comment: @aliboy..see question attachment. when I have small number of columns it dont help... such a ugly look...:(